# Node.js node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node

Tags: grpc-node

I was doing a proof of concept on gRPC using node.js

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "grpc-node-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "grpc": "^1.11.0",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1"
  }
}
```

After writing in proto file, client and server files. When I run the command node server.js
I got the following error

```
PS C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo> node server.js
C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:58
    throw e;
    ^

Error: Failed to load C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node. \\?\C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:32:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
PS C:\Learnings\node\grpc-nodejs-demo>
```

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I did the following steps to resolve the issue

- I was missing node-gyp - which is Node.js native addon build tool. It can be installed by

  npm install -g node-gyp
- Install Python
- Install Visual C++ Build Environment
- Clean up node-modules
- Then do in the folder `npm install`

The following link talks the above steps in detail:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows